# Does Jetpack Compose's LazyVerticalGrid have span strategy

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyVerticalGrid with 2 cells.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    content = {
        items(moviePagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
            val movie = moviePagingItems[index] ?: return@items
            MovieItem(movie, Modifier.preferredHeight(320.dp))
        }
        renderLoading(moviePagingItems.loadState)
    }
)
```

[image]

I am trying to show full width loading with `LazyGridScope`'s `fillParentMaxSize` modifier.

```
fun LazyGridScope.renderLoading(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
  when {
    loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
        item {
            LoadingColumn("Fetching movies", Modifier.fillParentMaxSize())
        }
    }
    loadState.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
        item {
            LoadingRow(title = "Fetching more movies")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But since we have 2 cells, the loading can occupy half of the screen. Like this:

[image]

Is there a way my loading view can occupy full width?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jetpack Compose `1.1.0-beta03` version includes horizontal span support for `LazyVerticalGrid`.

Here is the example usage:

```
private const val CELL_COUNT = 2

private val span: (LazyGridItemSpanScope) -> GridItemSpan = { GridItemSpan(CELL_COUNT) }

LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(CELL_COUNT),
    content = {
        items(moviePagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
            val movie = moviePagingItems.peek(index) ?: return@items
            Movie(movie)
        }
        renderLoading(moviePagingItems.loadState)
    }
}

private fun LazyGridScope.renderLoading(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
    if (loadState.append !is LoadState.Loading) return

    item(span = span) {
        val title = stringResource(R.string.fetching_more_movies)
        LoadingRow(title = title)
    }
}
```

Code examples of this answer can be found at: [Jetflix/MoviesGrid.kt](https://github.com/yasinkacmaz/jetflix/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yasinkacmaz/jetflix/ui/movies/MoviesGrid.kt)

Comment: How to set the span per item?

Comment: @Rafael `items` method has a `span` parameter which has an index. You can determine each span in that.

Answer (score 12):

`LazyVerticalGrid` has a span strategy built into `items()` and `itemsIndexed()`

```
@Composable
fun SpanLazyVerticalGrid(cols: Int, itemList: List<String>) {
    val lazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()
    LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(cols),
            state = lazyGridState
    ) {
        items(itemList, span = { item ->
            val lowercase = item.lowercase()
            val span = if (lowercase.startsWith("a") || lowercase.lowercase().startsWith("b") || lowercase.lowercase().startsWith("d")) {
                cols
            }
            else {
                1
            }
            GridItemSpan(span)
        }) { item ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(150.dp)
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .background(Color.Black)
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                        text = item,
                        fontSize = 18.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

'

```
val names = listOf("Alice", "Bob", "Cindy", "Doug", "Ernie", "Fred", "George", "Harris")
SpanLazyVerticalGrid(
        cols = 3,
        itemList = names
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
var cellState by remember { mutableStateOf(2) }
LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(cellState),
    content = {
        items(moviePagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
            val movie = moviePagingItems[index] ?: return@items
            MovieItem(movie, Modifier.preferredHeight(320.dp))
        }
        renderLoading(moviePagingItems.loadState) {
            cellState = it
        }
    }
)
```

The `renderLoading` function:

```
fun LazyGridScope.renderLoading(loadState: CombinedLoadStates, span: (Int) -> Unit) {
    when {
        loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
            item {
                LoadingColumn("Fetching movies", Modifier.fillParentMaxSize())
            }
            span(1)
        }
        ...
        else -> span(2)
    }
  
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant idea, thanks. But I have another problem. I have pagination and when `loadState.append` I cannot change grid cell count because I already have items.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an issue for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/176758183

Current workaround I have is to use `LazyColumn` and implement items or header.

```
override val content: @Composable () -> Unit = {
    LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
            content = {
                items(colors.chunked(3), itemContent = {

                    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
                        val modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                        it.forEach {
                            ColorItem(modifier, it)
                        }
                        for (i in 1..(3 - it.size)) {
                            Spacer(modifier)
                        }
                    }
                })
                item {
                    Text(
                            text = stringResource(R.string.themed_colors),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3
                    )
                }
                items(themedColors.chunked(3), itemContent = {
                    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
                        val modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                        it.forEach {
                            ColorItem(modifier, it)
                        }
                        for (i in 1..(3 - it.size)) {
                            Spacer(modifier)
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
}
```

Comment: I have had this behaviour, chunked with a paginated list was giving me unexpected placements. Otherwise, this works for now.

Comment: then maybe problem is not about grids. have you tried an item per line just to see if it works well with pagination?

Comment: hmm, I cannot say more without seeing more code.

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913480/2098878

Answer (score 1):

I have designed a user interface where I want to display cards in a single cell for "Type A" and in double cells for "Type B". I was able to achieve this using the **span** attribute in **items**.

However, I recently discovered that LazyVerticalGrid already has a span strategy built into items() and itemsIndexed().

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
@Composable
internal fun SearchSlimCardContent(activityGroup: List<ActivityGroup?>) {

    val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp

    val list = activityGroup.flatMap { group ->
        group?.activityTiles ?: emptyList()
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.height(screenHeight.dp)) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
        ) {
            items(list, span = { tile ->
                val span = if (tile.__typename == "Type A") {
                    2
                } else {
                    1
                }
                GridItemSpan(span)
            }
            ) { tiles ->
                when (tiles.__typename) {
                    "Type A" ->
                        ActivitySearchBanner(
                            activityMessagingTile = tiles.fragments.activityMessagingTile
                        )
                    "Type B" ->
                        ActivitySlimCardTile(
                            activityTile = tiles.fragments.activityTile
                        )
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[And this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmK1Y.png)