# What is the equivalent of [NestedScrollView + RecyclerView] or [Nested RecyclerView (Recycler inside another recycler) in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create the following layout in Jetpack compose.
[image]

I've tried creating two lists inside a vertical scrollable Box but that's not possible as I got the this error:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like ScrollableContainer and LazyColumn is not allowed. If you want to add a header before the list of items please take a look on LazyColumn component which has a DSL api which allows to first add a header via item() function and then the list of items via items()."

I've tried creating two different lists inside a parent list by using the following code, but that doesn't work either.

```
@Composable
fun MainList() {
    LazyColumn() {
        
        item {
            /* LazyRow code here */
        }
        
        item {
            /* LazyColumn code here */
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm clueless about what else could I try to achieve two lists (one vertical and one horizontal) on the same activity and keep the activity vertically scrollable too.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think the best option, would be if the `LazyVerticalGrid` allows some sort of expand logic on each item, but looks like it's not supported yet (beta-03).

So I'm leaving here my solution using one single `LazyColumn` for the entire list and `LazyRow` for "My Books" section.

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) {
    // My Books section
    item {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text("My Books")
            LazyRow {
                items(books) { item ->
                    // Each Item
                }
            }
        }

    }
    // Whishlisted Books title
    item {
        Text("Whishlisted Books", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4)
    }
    // Turning the list in a list of lists of two elements each
    items(wishlisted.windowed(2, 2, true)) { item ->
        Row {
            // Draw item[0]
            // Draw item[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my [gist with the full solution](https://gist.github.com/nglauber/64df9091c2e76bde648ce48d585ed3e1) and the result is listed below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write a detailed reply. It works like a charm :)

Comment: Flow seems much more easy than making the views via XML it's crazy...

Comment: Did you mean "spanning" when you said "expand logic"? If so, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70555159/685429

Answer (score 4):

An alternative equivalent of nested RecyclerViews is nested LazyColumns, where the ***heights*** of the inner LazyColumns are specified or constant, and the inner LazyColumns are placed inside *item {}* blocks.

Unlike the accepted answer, this approach relies on the .height() modifier to avoid the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like ScrollableContainer and LazyColumn is not allowed... " error. Also, this approach addresses the scenario of nested scrolling in the same direction.

Here is an example code and output.

```
    @Composable
    fun NestedLists() {
        LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(12.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            //Header for first inner list
            item {
                Text(text = "List of numbers:", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
            }
            // First, scrollable, inner list
            item {
                // Note the important height modifier.
                LazyColumn(Modifier.height(100.dp)){
                    val numbersList = (0 .. 400 step 4).toList()
                    itemsIndexed(numbersList) { index, multipleOf4 ->
                        Text(text = "$multipleOf4", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color.Blue))
                    }
                }
            }

        // Header for second inner list
        item {
            Text(text = "List of letters:", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
        }
        // Second, scrollable, inner list
        item {
            // Note the important height modifier.
            LazyColumn(Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
                val lettersList = ('a' .. 'z').toList()
                itemsIndexed(lettersList) { index, letter ->
                    Text(text = "$letter", style = TextStyle(color = Color.Blue, fontSize = 22.sp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference between accepted answer and your answer?

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, my answer relies on the .height() modifier to avoid the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like ScrollableContainer and LazyColumn is not allowed... " error.  Also, my answer addresses the scenario of nested scrolling in the same direction. Finally, in my example, the bottom list can scroll independently of the top one.  Thanks for your clarification comment :)!

Comment: ohh ok. Thanks for your clarification. I thought it's same as accepted answer.

Comment: @CherifDiallo: Wow, that's useful clarification. Could you _edit_ that into your answer, so that future readers aren't confused by the difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
   Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

        LazyRow() {
            items(itemsList){
                  //.....
                }
        }

       LazyColumn() {
           items(itemsList2){
               //..
           }
       }
    }
```

[image]

or:

```
   Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

        LazyRow() {
            items(itemsList){
               //....
            }
        }
       
       LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
           items(itemsList2.size){
               //....
           }
       }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide a detailed solution. Although the solution is accurate, but it doesn't scroll the entire activity. So I'm going to merge the solution provided by you (the grid part) and @nglauber. Thanks again.

Comment: Quick Question: Since here LazyVerticalGrid is wrapped in a simple Column, do you still get recycling advantage of LazyVerticalGrid? Or Column will try to populate all content including LazyVerticalGrid on first render?