two columns? Card in compose
The DishCard function works correctly. How can I display the items in two columns?
my code is
@Composable
fun PopularItems(
    popularItems: List<Recipe>,
    searchItems: List<SearchResult>,
    recipeDetailScreenViewModel: RecipeDetailScreenViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController,
    name: String?,
    homeScreenViewModel: HomeScreenViewModel,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    ) {
        item { HeaderText(name = name) }
        item { CustomSearchBar(navController, homeScreenViewModel) }
        item {
            Text(
                text = "Recipes",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 30.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 30.sp,
            )
        }

        items(popularItems) { recipe ->
            ExampleGrid(data = popularItems)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExampleGrid(data: List<Recipe>) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
    ) {
        items(data.size) { index ->
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = data[index].title,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

My error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779174/14883879
have a look. does that solve your problem

Please reduce your code to a [mre] and provide a better title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title
