How to nest verticall scrollable inside another verticall scrollable in Compose?
What can I do if I need to put a lazycolumn inside a lazycolumn? I'm getting this error:

IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured
with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed.

I know that as doc says (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/lists#avoid-nesting-scrollable), we must avoid nesting components scrollable in the same direction.
But my app is an special app, like an "app constructor" in which the user can construct an app using different types of items, for example: texts, images, vertical scroll containers (lazycolumns), horizontal scroll containers (lazyrows), etc and for example, the user is free to put a vertical scroll, with some text and an horizontall scroll, and that horizontal scroll can have a verticall scroll inside.
I need to know how to achieve this

You can put a LazyColumn into another LazyColumn or any other Composable with scroll Modifier but you can't have nested scrollable Composable with Constraints with maxWidth/Height equal to Constraints.Infinity in scroll direction because scroll Modifier has a check if incoming Constrains have max Constraints.Infinity. If you change this infinite Constraints.Infinity to something finite you can put a scrollable inside another one.
I used LazyColumn in snippets but this answer is about putting a scrollable into another scrollable, no matter which one both are, to have nested scrollable if you ever nested scrollable Composables. If you are using LazyColumn/Row, etc. you should use items or item but in some cases that you might need nested scrollable Composable then you can check section below.
Setting heightIn(max) to finite changes maxHeight(this is biggest height a Composable can be measured with) nested scrollable Composable can be measured between min-max so it can be as big as its content or you can set a fixed height to limit nested Composable so it does not crash with

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is
disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like
LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a
header before the list of items please add a header as a separate
item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are
could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added
into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied
Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout.
Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the
hierarchy above the scrolling container.

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/CheckScrollableContainerConstraints.kt;l=30
@Preview
@Composable
fun ScrollTest() {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {

        item {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp).background(Color.Red))
        }

        item {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    // without this modifier crash happens
                    .heightIn(
            // This number is an arbitrary height for demonstration, you can use screen height or 
           // another number to limit how big this LazyColumn should be
                        max = Short.MAX_VALUE.toInt().dp
                    ),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(20) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Nested Row $it",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        items(20) {
            Text(
                text = "Outer Row $it",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

Edit
This max number presents how tall LazyColumn can be. The bigger it is the more items will be composed at once and it will be less lazier more like Column with scroll.
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        // without this modifier crash happens
        .heightIn(
            max = Short.MAX_VALUE.toInt().dp
        ),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    items(2000) {

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            println("Recomposing item: $it")
        }
        
        Text(
            text = "Nested Row $it",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp)
        )
    }
}

Composes 582 on my emulator. And that's why there is a warning in the link i shared about performance.
This approach is useful when you don't know 5-10 item long LazyColumn can be, and using big number to measure it's height between 0 and some big number to get content height or putting a LazyGrid with small number of items into a LazyColumn instead of implementing it yourself.
When you wish to put a LazyList into another one consider the fact that depending how big its viewport is number of items it composes changes also.

You can read about Constraints, infinite Constraints, size Modifiers in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779226/android-jetpack-compose-width-height-size-modifier-vs-requiredwidth-requir/73316247#73316247. And sample for putting vertical grid into another composable https://stackoverflow.com/a/77421773/5457853

.heightIn(max = Short.MAX_VALUE.toInt().dp), worked perfectly! great job! thanks

probably Short.MAX_VALUE is a low value and I must add more? will a lazycolumn with 999999 items have a enormous height? or the lazy loading with reusing of items will limit heigh to a normal amount?

Yes, it's enormous height, it's an assumption that you won't have that many items. But it doesn't compose all of them. The point is you need to set a finite value that is bigger than your content to all of them fit without inner scrolling. Or set a smaller number to limit that height. It's a matter of choice. I just showed that why it crashes and how you can over come and how you can shape your design with this info based on how LazyColumn or actually Modifier.scroll is designed

It's almost always it's better to use items instead of nested LazyColumn but in some edge cases this is the approach for not to have that exception. Change infinite max number to finite one to measure content between min and max dimension of Constraints. You can see in the vertical grid link i used 1000.dp but the point is using some finite number. Even though Constraints.Infinity is actually Int:MAX_VALUE it's considered as infinite in jetpack compose. Not for this but other operations like creating your own layout too

And last but not least if you need an nested LazyColumn often best approach is to limit it with screen height like you set outer LazyColumn with fillMaxHeight so it would recompose only items that can fit your screen. That max number is some arbitrary number you can change based on your design

is the lazy behaviour still enabled if we use heightIn? or will it loose all the benfits and behave like a normal Column? I mean... if got 100 elements, loading 100 at once even the not visible ones.

Lazy behavior is enabled no matter how big you set Viewport is. But number of items in composition will differ as in my edit. It seems that there is a threshold for height to limit number of items to be composed at once. On my device i see 582 items. And it will always be the number how many items will be recomposed at once. If you limit max height to screen height number of items composed initially will be equal to how it would be if it wasn't a nested layout. You can set maxHeight for a LazyColumn that is bigger than screen height and it would behave same as well.

As i try to explain "very long" answer for your other question also in comment section link about Constraints, it depends on Constraints that is passed to might change how it behaves. Constraints are building blocks of size modifiers and Layouts.  Pass modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().requiredHeight(2000.dp) or some height value bigger than screen height LazyColumn, and observe that more items are recomposed than on visible on screen. You can also use Modifier.layout. I mean a LazyColumn that is not nested by the way.

Lazy behavior depends on how big viewport is nested or not. If viewport is as tall as to contain 100 items, then 100 items are composed. But as i observed while testing there is number most likely based on height of viewport that can be compose at once. Try the snippet i added in edit

well, then it's like if I'm using a column, is loading everything instead of only the visible items. Does exist a possibility to achieve it without losing the benefits of lazycolumn? I need to be able to manage hundreds of items so I need to do it without loading all of them

You can set limit smaller as i mentioned in edit and in comments, preferably to outer LazyColumn height or screen height. This part has nothing to do with nesting really. It's more about how LazyColumn works if you set its height bigger than parent. This is totally separate question and i answered it several times. If you set max 2 items tall it would only compose 3 items if you set height 5 items tall 6 and so on.

You say that "You can set limit smaller as i mentioned" but I can't do that, because if I do that, then, my lazycolumn can't manage hundreds of items, just a few... and I need to manage hundreds. So definitivelly, I need to force a huge height and then I loose all the benefits of lazy column and it's like I'm using a Column. Am I right? Did I missunderstood anything? is there a way to achieve my objective without losing the lazycolumn benefits?

please can you answer to my previous comment?

Short.MAX_VALUE = 32767
Using a large height value like Short.MAX_VALUE or 32767.dp may cause all items in the LazyColumn to load unnecessarily, bypassing its built-in optimizations.
A better approach is to set the maximum height to the screen height, so the LazyColumn loads items only up to the screen height.
@Composable
fun LazyColumnInsideLazyColum() {
    val maxWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
    val maxHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(maxHeight).width(maxWidth)) {
        item {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .heightIn(max = maxHeight)
                    .width(maxWidth)
            ) {
                items(20_000) {
                    println(it)
                    Text(
                        text = "Nested Row $it",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(maxWidth)
                            .padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


And last but not least if you need an nested LazyColumn often best approach is to limit it with screen height like you set outer LazyColumn with fillMaxHeight so it would recompose only items that can fit your screen.. This is exactly what i posted in the comment also available in commented code and in edit section too. And as i mentioned in the answer that number is arbitrary based on your design. You sound like i strictly said use that number

You can use both approaches. BoxWithConstraints is a SubcomposeLayout it gets Constraints first, and only once if they don't change, and pass to content and composes it. You can get height as you did with LocalConfiguration  or with BoxWithConstraints. This is also what i suggested if you have hundreds of items but it's a design decision really. Consider for instance designer said use have a nested scrollable that contain 5 items most but only 2 should be visible at same time, in that case you can set heighIn(max = 2*itemHeight), etc. This is a number you should choose based on design

i think i explain myself wrong bro (maybe my english not fluent). yes you are right best approach should be "to limit it with screen height like you set outer LazyColumn height". i thought when we use constraint as example height of BoxWithConstraints will be changed frequently but after i read and test it, it don't changed if not neccessary.  thank you for post it change my opinion.

The point is turning infinite max value of Constraints to finite value to pass https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/CheckScrollableContainerConstraints.kt;l=30 check if you ever need nested scrolling. It doesn't have to be lazyColumn as well. You can even have a scrollable Canvas inside a scrollable Column with other items, etc. And you might also decide to have a LazyColumn that can compose more items than one that is not visible on screen by setting bigger number.

yes you are right this designer decision will say this should show only 5 items or fill all screen will items. thank you for answers it really helped me.

Outer lazyColumn measured sizes will be changed according insider lazyColumn but if insider lazycolumn not has finite size it will throw infinite crash. when we set height according our desicions it will be finite measered size and inseder column will works without any crashes.

Hi, if I use your proposal, what happens if my list has hundreds of items? will they be displayed? or will only display the first ones that fit in the height screen?

hi, if you use height of screen, only the first ones that fit into the height screen will be shown.
