# LazyColumn inside vertically scrollable Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(mainScrollState))` and I want to use `LazyColumn` inside `Column` WITHOUT specifying height of `LazyColumn` explicitly.

Now it gives me  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed.`

I tried using `NestedScrollConnection` but it didn't give me right solution. Any workarounds?

My whole composable looks like:

```
Scaffold() {
    Column() {
       Column() { 
          LazyColumn { ... }
       }
       Column() { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on how many elements you have above the LazyColumn, you could actually list them as elements at the start of the LazyColumn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of \[NestedScrollView + RecyclerView\] or \[Nested RecyclerView (Recycler inside another recycler) in Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908737/what-is-the-equivalent-of-nestedscrollview-recyclerview-or-nested-recyclerv)

Comment: Unfortunately, no
I've seen these answers, but those variants do not apply to my case.

Comment: Check this out: https://youtu.be/1ANt65eoNhQ?t=896

Comment: I think this is the easiest and most correct answer :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.heightIn(2000.dp) // set the maximum height possible in your case
    ) {
        // your content
    }
}
```

You may use `heightIn()`, so compose will know the exact height of element. This works like wrapContentHeight, but there is a maximum height allowed

I think it's more suitable for small number of items, though